# Display Via GoDaddy Forwarding is different

Tags: html, css

Everything is small when I visit my site(hosted on github) via GoDaddy domain.

so when I visit the site on github pages everything looks exactly how I want. But when I go see it via the domain i have on GoDaddy things are different usually smaller text and images.

ps the domain is forwarding(with masking) to my github pages site

this seems to only happen with the masking.

Comment: Screenshots and/or a link would be helpful. It's probably due to some kind of default styling on Github Pages.

Comment: Could be browser zoom, since this is linked to the domain. If using Chrome, try pressing Control - 0 (zero) to see if the size corrects itself. Other browsers probably have similar hotkeys.